# Phone sometimes skips function inside loop in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a POS app that works with a thermal printer with the Bluetooth Serial plugin. When the order is too long, I split the invoice in chunks of 300 bits. On my phone it works well 100% of the time, but when I try to use a Huawei phone (the one that is being used in the store) it skips one or several iterations of the print call in the loop.

I don’t know it if is an async/await issue, or a Bluetooth communication issue. Anyway there are the 2 functions I use for printing.

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Also, I split the order into chunks because when the order is too long, some printers stop printing the invoice after 5 seconds or so...

```
async printTicket(order: Order, sale?: Sale) {
  let ticket: any[] = await this._printer.generateReceipt(order, sale);
  let chunks: any[] = await chunk(ticket, 300);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    this._printer.getDefaultPrinter().then(async printer => {
      if (printer) {
        for (let index = 0; index < chunks.length; index++) {
          await this.sendToPrinter(chunks[index], index, chunks.length, printer.address);
          await this._misc.delay(100);
        }
        res(ticket)
      } else {
        this._misc.presentSimpleAlert('Error', '', 'Impresora no seleccionada');
        rej()
      }
    }).catch(error => rej(error))
  })
}
async sendToPrinter(data, index, total, address) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const bt = this._printer.connectBT(address).subscribe(async _ => {
      this._misc.presentToast("Imprimiendo parte " + (index + 1) + ' de ' + total);
      await this._printer.writeData(data);
      this._printer.deviceDisconnected().then(res => {
        this._misc.presentToast("Dispositivo bluetooth desconectado");
        bt.unsubscribe()
        resolve(data);
      }).catch(err => reject(err));
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it seems like you are using simple for-loop to go through async method (sendToPronter) serially:

```
    for (let index = 0; index < chunks.length; index++) {
      await this.sendToPrinter(chunks[index], index, chunks.length, printer.address);
      await this._misc.delay(100);
    }
```

despite you are using "await" in fact your loop does not wait for previous promise to fully resolve.

You need to leverage different type of loop here if you want your loop to actually await until previous promise is resolved:

```
async function processArray(array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    await delayedLog(item);
  }
  console.log('Done!');
}
```

So in your case should be something like:

```
async printTicket(order: Order, sale?: Sale) {
  let ticket: any[] = await this._printer.generateReceipt(order, sale);
  let chunks: any[] = await chunk(ticket, 300);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    this._printer.getDefaultPrinter().then(async printer => {
      if (printer) {
        for (const [index,chunk] of chunks.entries()) {
          await this.sendToPrinter(chunk, index, chunks.length, printer.address);
          await this._misc.delay(100);
        }
        res(ticket)
      } else {
        this._misc.presentSimpleAlert('Error', '', 'Impresora no seleccionada');
        rej()
      }
    }).catch(error => rej(error))
  })
}

async sendToPrinter(data, index, total, address) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const bt = this._printer.connectBT(address).subscribe(async _ => {
      this._misc.presentToast("Imprimiendo parte " + (index + 1) + ' de ' + total);
      await this._printer.writeData(data);
      this._printer.deviceDisconnected().then(res => {
        this._misc.presentToast("Dispositivo bluetooth desconectado");
        bt.unsubscribe()
        resolve(data);
      }).catch(err => reject(err));
    })
  })
}
```

Please note I used destructuring to obtain 'index' while iterating using ES6 .entries() method of an array. Depending on your requirements you might need to adjust this.

You can learn more here: https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/

Comment: Well... it actually worked as intented on my phone, but still this Huawei phone chops the middle part of the print

Comment: what do you mean by "chops"? can you try using for-in loop and see what result it gives on Huawei?

Comment: Sure, that particular smartphone (Huawei Y6) won't  call the functions inside the loop correctly. With your particular solution it skips the last call of the data array. As I said I don't know why it is a specific problem with that phone but well, that's the one they need to use in the store (they bought 50 of them)